# How to align elements in a li

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align three things in a li with a border. A `<h1>` to the left, a `<p>` to the middle, and a `<img>` to the right. Currently I'm doing it using the CSS margin property, but since the elements change in width and height, that ends up looking good on some and worse on others:

[image: Here is image 1]

*The first looks bad, but the second one has wider elements and looks better.*

Here is the relevant HTML code I'm currently using:

And CSS:

````
css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#container{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 40rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#raidList{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#raidList li{
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  min-height: calc(1rem + 96px);
  margin: 1.75rem 0;
  box-shadow: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0.6rem rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 0.5rem 1.125rem rgba(75,0,0,0.05);
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#raidList li img{
  margin-left: calc(100% - (160px + 50%));
  float: right;
}

#raidList li h1{
  margin: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
  float: left;
}

#raidList li p{
  margin-left: calc(50% - 160px);
}

#raidList li > *{
  position: relative;
}```
````

How can I fix this? Keep in mind that it's a li and not a div. Thanks!

Comment: share your html code

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have changed to make it work as you want:

```
.container{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.raidList{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.raidList li{
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    min-height: calc(1rem + 96px);
    margin: 1.75rem 0;
    box-shadow: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0.6rem rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 0.5rem 1.125rem rgba(75,0,0,0.05);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: none;
}
```

For your "li" try using justify-content instead of align-content and set it to center.
I also changed raidList to a display flex so it goes horizontally and so I can apply the justify-content to the center.

This works just fine, I may have changed some values such as width or heigth but you can vary those as you like.

You can add as many elements as you want, the "li" will justify them.

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of layout that flexbox is made for -
simply apply `display: flex` to the li - and `align-items:center`- to vertically center everything and then `justify-content: space-between` to space them out horizontally

That said - you really shouldn't be using a h1 on every row - h1s are intended to be the top level heading and indicate the highest level of content heading for the page.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  list-style: none;
}

h1 {
margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 16px 0;
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li{
 border-bottom: solid 1px red;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="flex-container">
    <h1>left content</h1>
    <p>middle content</p>
    <span>right content</span>
  </li>
    <li class="flex-container">
    <h1>left content</h1>
    <p>middle content</p>
    <span>right content</span>
  </li>
    <li class="flex-container">
    <h1>left content</h1>
    <p>middle content</p>
    <span>right content</span>
  </li>
 </ul>
```